# Regex condition on first and last characters

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I write a regex to match a string that does not start or end with a white space character? A matching string can have any character in the middle, and importantly, a single-character string should match.

My attempt was:

```
/\A\S.*\S\z/
```

but this will not match a single character.

Comment: Give an example of the string you want to match.

Comment: "a" but not " a" or "a "

Comment: Why not simply do it without regex? first and last char are not " ". In python it would be: `if s[0]!=' ' and s[-1]!=' '`

Comment: well its not just spaces that are not allowed but all white space characters; furthermore i just want to know how to do it

Comment: kempchee, do you want one or substring that matches or all substrings that match? Please clariy, preferably with an edit.

Comment: @kempchee Your question was kind of misleading. Your attempted regex not only fails to match a single-character string, but also an empty string. Your emphasis on the fact that it fails to match a single-character string may have led people whose comprehension skill is not so high to think that empty strings should be excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the cases where you should not attempt to build a regex that matches something, but rather a regex that matches **the complement of something**, and use the regex negatively.

```
re = /\A\s|\s\z/
re !~ " "     # => false
re !~ ""      # => true
re !~ "sss"   # => true
re !~ "s ss"  # => true
re !~ " s ss" # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
is_ok = lambda do |str|
  a, z = str.chars.first, str.chars.last
  "#{a}#{z}" =~ / |\n|\t/ ? false : true
end


#"more elegant" (yeah dude I rock)
is_ok = lambda {|str| [0, -1].map{|i| str.chars[i] }.join =~ / |\n|\t/ ? false : true}
```

Comment: This answer is the only one at the moment besides my answer that gives the desired result, but not so elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\A\S+(?:\s*\S+)*\Z
```

You can play with the Test String part of [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/uZ1xN5/3) to see how this works. I'm assuming that strings can span multiple lines, hence the `\A` and `\Z`

In Ruby, something like:

```
if subject =~ /\A\S+(?:\s*\S+)*\Z/
    match = $&
```

**Explanation**

- The `\A` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the subject string
- `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters (including tabs, newlines etc.) Alternaltely, if you want to allow newlines at the beginning but only want to exclude a space character, you can use `[^ ]+` instead of `\S+`
- `(?:\s*\S+)` matches any number of optional whitespace characters, followed by one or more non-space characters
- The `*` quantifier repeats that zero or more times
- The `\Z` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the subject string

Comment: Hi there, I'm a working regex with an explanation and a drive-by downvote!

Answer (score -1):

Use lookaheads, like this:

```
\A(?=\S).*\S\Z
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cO9yQ2/5)

This matches the start of the string and requires (1) that the first character be a non-whitespace character and (2) that the last character be a non-whitespace character.

Matches:

- `a`
- `a    b`
- `a b c d 1231 e`

Non matches:

- (just a space)
- `a` (leading space)
- `b` (trailing space)
- empty string

Comment: But your regex didn't matches anything.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Technically, you are correct; the first version just tested whether the string starts or ends with whitespace, but the match itself was zero-length. I added `.+` to the end, and now it also matches the entire string.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it would be better if your regex is [`\A(?=\S).*\S\Z`](http://regex101.com/r/cO9yQ2/4)